# RuntimeError: Attempting to deserialize object on a CUDA device

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, machine-learning, computer-vision

I encounter a `RunTimeError` while I am trying to run the code in my machine's CPU instead of GPU. The code is originally from this GitHub project - [IBD: Interpretable Basis Decomposition for Visual Explanation](https://github.com/CSAILVision/IBD). This is for a research project. I tried putting the CUDA as `false` and looked at other solutions on this website.

```
GPU = False               # running on GPU is highly suggested
CLEAN = False             # set to "True" if you want to clean the temporary large files after generating result
APP = "classification"    # Do not change! mode choide: "classification", "imagecap", "vqa". Currently "imagecap" and "vqa" are not supported.
CATAGORIES = ["object", "part"]   # Do not change! concept categories that are chosen to detect: "object", "part", "scene", "material", "texture", "color"

CAM_THRESHOLD = 0.5                 # the threshold used for CAM visualization
FONT_PATH = "components/font.ttc"   # font file path
FONT_SIZE = 26                      # font size
SEG_RESOLUTION = 7                  # the resolution of cam map
BASIS_NUM = 7                       # In decomposition, this is to decide how many concepts are used to interpret the weight vector of a class.
```

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 22, in <module>
    model = loadmodel()
  File "/home/joshuayun/Desktop/IBD/loader/model_loader.py", line 48, in loadmodel
    checkpoint = torch.load(settings.MODEL_FILE)
  File "/home/joshuayun/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 387, in load
    return _load(f, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
  File "/home/joshuayun/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 574, in _load
    result = unpickler.load()
  File "/home/joshuayun/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 537, in persistent_load
    deserialized_objects[root_key] = restore_location(obj, location)
  File "/home/joshuayun/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 119, in default_restore_location
    result = fn(storage, location)
  File "/home/joshuayun/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 95, in _cuda_deserialize
    device = validate_cuda_device(location)
  File "/home/joshuayun/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 79, in validate_cuda_device
    raise RuntimeError('Attempting to deserialize object on a CUDA '
RuntimeError: Attempting to deserialize object on a CUDA device but 
  torch.cuda.is_available() is False. If you are running on a CPU-only machine, 
  please use torch.load with map_location='cpu' to map your storages to the CPU.
```

Comment: Edited the question for clarity.

Answer (score 63):

If you don't have gpu then use **map_location=torch.device('cpu')** with load model.load()

```
my_model = net.load_state_dict(torch.load('classifier.pt', map_location=torch.device('cpu')))
```

Comment: You still get the same warning with this code, it's likely because you dumped it with Pickle instead of Pytorch. Do `torch.save` instead of `pickle.dump`.

Answer (score 41):

Just giving a smaller answer. To solve this, you could change the parameters of the function named `load()` in the `serialization.py` file. This is stored in: `./site-package/torch/serialization.py`

Write:

```
def load(f, map_location='cpu', pickle_module=pickle, **pickle_load_args):
```

instead of:

```
def load(f, map_location=None, pickle_module=pickle, **pickle_load_args):
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 24):

"If you are running on a CPU-only machine, please use torch.load with map_location=torch.device('cpu') to map your storages to the CPU."

```
model = torch.load('model/pytorch_resnet50.pth',map_location ='cpu')
```

Comment: This worked for me. Was trying to serialize and deserialize a PyTorch model as a pickle, which got the error in the OP's question, and led me to this answer

Answer (score 19):

I have tried add "map_location='cpu'" in load function, but it doesn't work for me.

If you use a model trained by GPU on a CPU only computer, then you may meet this bug. And you can try this solution.

[solution](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/16797#issuecomment-633423219)

```
class CPU_Unpickler(pickle.Unpickler):
    def find_class(self, module, name):
        if module == 'torch.storage' and name == '_load_from_bytes':
            return lambda b: torch.load(io.BytesIO(b), map_location='cpu')
        else: return super().find_class(module, name)

contents = CPU_Unpickler(f).load()
```

Comment: Thank you! So useful, I opened another (logged-in) browser profile just to come back and upvote. :-)

Comment: for some reason, torch was ignoring `map_location=torch.device("cpu")` whenever I used it, but this worked!

Comment: This works, the accepted answer didn't

Comment: This works even for loading objects with GPU tensors saved via pickle. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

You can remap the Tensor location at load time using the map_location argument to torch.load.

On the following repository,in file "test.py", model = loadmodel() calls the model_loader.py file to load the model with torch.load().

While this will only map storages from GPU0, add the map_location:

```
torch.load(settings.MODEL_FILE, map_location={'cuda:0': 'cpu'})
```

In the model_loader.py file, add, map_location={'cuda:0': 'cpu'} whereever, torch.load() function is called.

Answer (score 6):

You may have to re-install torch for your desired CUDA Toolkit version.

Lookup the command from [Getting Started](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/) page and re-install.

```bash
# uninstall first
pip uninstall torch torchvision torchaudio

# e.g. for CUDA Toolkit 1.8
pip install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118
```

Answer (score 4):

As you state the problem hints you are trying to use a cuda-model on non-cuda machine. Pay attention to the details of the error message - `please use torch.load with map_location='cpu' to map your storages to the CPU`. I've had similar problem when I tried to load (from a checkpoint) pre-trained model on my cpu-only machine. The model was trained on a cuda machine so it couldn't be properly loaded. Once I added the `map_location='cpu'` argument to the `load` method everything worked.

Comment: This may not be the case. I get this problem although I run the model on the same GPU machine that was trained on.

Comment: I'm also seeing this error on a GPU machine, `torch.cuda.is_available() --> True`

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem, Instead of modifying the existing code, which was running good yesterday, First I checked whether my GPU is free or not running

`nvidia-smi`

I could see that, its under utilized, therefore as traditional solution, I shutdown the laptop and restarted it and it got working.

(One thing I kept in mind that, earlier it was working and I haven't changed anything in code therefore it should work once I restart it and it got working and I was able to use the GPU)

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, this also happens with [portainer](https://www.portainer.io/), even though your machines have GPUs. A crude solution would be to just restart it. It usually happens if you fiddle with the state of the container after it has been deployed (e.g. you change the restart policies while the container is running), which makes me think it's some portainer issue.

Answer (score 1):

nothing worked for me-
my pickle was a custom object- in a script file with the line

```
device = torch.device("cuda")
```

finally, I managed to take Spikes [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68992197/13117615), and adapt it to my needs with simple open(path,"rb"), so for any other unfortunate developers:

```
class CPU_Unpickler(pickle.Unpickler):
    def find_class(self, module, name):
        if module == 'torch.storage' and name == '_load_from_bytes':
            return lambda b: torch.load(io.BytesIO(b), map_location='cpu')
        else: return super().find_class(module, name)

contents = CPU_Unpickler(open(path,"rb")).load()
```

Comment: It still doesn't work for me even if I use this instead. do you have any other solutions?

Answer (score 1):

There is much easier way. Just add map_location to `torch.load(path, map_location='cpu')` as `map_location='cpu'`:

```
def load_checkpoint(path) -> 'LanguageModel':
    checkpoint = torch.load(path, map_location='cpu')
    model = LanguageModel(
        number_of_tokens=checkpoint['number_of_tokens'],
        max_sequence_length=checkpoint['max_sequence_length'],
        embedding_dimension=checkpoint['embedding_dimension'],
        number_of_layers=checkpoint['number_of_layers'],
        number_of_heads=checkpoint['number_of_heads'],
        feed_forward_dimension=checkpoint['feed_forward_dimension'],
        dropout_rate=checkpoint['dropout_rate']
    ).to(get_device())
    model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['model_state_dict'])
    return model.to(get_device())
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution that works for me:
I was with cuda 12.1.1, pytorch==2.0.1 and torchvision-0.13.1a0.
Output of torch.cuda.is_available() was FALSE

First, I removed these packages

> conda remove pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit pytorch

Then

> conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=11.7 -c pytorch -c nvidia

In the end, package versions were pytorch-2.0.1, torchvision-0.15.2, and of course cuda 11.7. And output of torch.cuda.is_available() is now TRUE